# requested operation is not supported in result sets

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, jtable

I need to display the data returned from a SQL SERVER stored procedure in a Jtable, and yet I have not been able to do it because it gives me the following error: the requested operation is not supported on forwarding-only result sets.

this is the code that I implemented:

```
try 
        {

            CallableStatement mostararPacientesAusentes = conexionBBDD.getConexionBBDD()
            .prepareCall("{call mostararPacientesAusentes()}");

            ResultSet tabla = mostararPacientesAusentes.executeQuery();
            
             
            
            AbstractTableModel mTN=new ModeloTabla(tabla);
            
            ventanaNotificacion.getTabla().setModel(mTN);
            ventanaNotificacion.getTabla().validate();
             

        } catch (SQLException e1) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage(), "BBDD", 2, null);
             
        }
```

and this is the class that inherits AbstractTableModel

```
public class ModeloTabla extends AbstractTableModel {

    private ResultSet tabla;
    private ResultSetMetaData datosBBDD;
    
    
    public ModeloTabla(ResultSet unResulset)
    {
        tabla=unResulset;
        
        try
        {
            datosBBDD=tabla.getMetaData();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
             
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
         
        try
        {
            tabla.absolute(rowIndex+1);
            return tabla.getObject(columnIndex+1);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } 
    }
    
    public String getColumnName(int c)
    {
         
        try 
        {
            return  datosBBDD.getColumnName(c+1);
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
             
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
     
        try {
         
             tabla.last();
             
             
            return tabla.getRow();
            
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 0;
        }
    
        
    }
     

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() 
    {
         
        try
        {
            return datosBBDD.getColumnCount();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

The titles of the columns of the table show it in the JTable, but the data does not.
I have already searched unsuccessfully for information to solve the problem.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSet.html) of `ResultSet`:

> ... A default ResultSet object is not updatable and has a cursor that **moves forward only**. Thus, you can iterate through it only once and only from the first row to the last row. **It is possible to produce ResultSet objects that are scrollable** and/or updatable. ...

There is a version of [prepareCall()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall(java.lang.String,int,int)) that accepts additional arguments to do that, like in:

```
...prepareCall("{call mostararPacientesAusentes()}",
               ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
               ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Please check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareCall(java.lang.String,int,int)) for other constants/types.

---

I am not sure if using a `ResultSet` to maintain the data is such a good idea - it is probably holding a lot of resources (connection, statement, ...) - IMHO better read the data once and save it in a list or similar structure; releasing the database resources ASAP.

Comment: Brilliant. Her contribution has helped me. Thank you very much.